# Getting a variable/age data through jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain

I have a central page that generates directory names on the server and I need to pull that into my page. Currently it's on two separate domains. I was using `$.get('url')` but since it was on different domains, I was getting the following error:

> Origin http://domain is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I swapped to using `$.getJSON('url');` and it retrieved the information that I needed, but I got

> Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token

as it wasn't in JSON format. All I want is to be able to access the generated directory name.

Any pointers?

Comment: You need to show some code, but `getJSON` won't work either. What you need is JSONP

Comment: the directory name isnt coming back in json, the json method was the only way  could get directory name back to my page without the access-control-allow-origin error

Comment: I don't think you're following Pekka's comment, the response can *only* be in JSONP, the security wouldn't be there if you can just bypass it with another method.  JSONP is a line of JavaScript that comes back in a `<script>` tag for execution...you can just fetch *any* content with it, it needs to be JSONP.

Comment: so what is the syntax for retrieving  a directory name generated by a php file? I have tried multple combinations of $.get $.getjson $.jsonp and all i want is to retrieve the string from the url. i could be tempted to drop down into php to get the directory name but i would rather leave it to the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jsonP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) parameter for cross domain calls. Also search for [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) or long polling.